# Apache configuration and session variable SERVER_NAME

Tags: php, apache, centos, virtualhost

as part of my daily routine I maintain a web site (not developed by me, i am not a web developer) that has many look and feel based on the incoming URL.
Recently a customer registered a new domain for a new L&F, I've made all the configuration on the server as usual (i have a manual how to do this) but this time it does not work.

I have serveral Virtual Host in the /etc/httpd/conf.d, they are all the same

```
    # The virtual host configuration for my.website.com
    #<Directory "/var/www/my.website.com/html">

    <Directory "/var/www/my.website.com/html">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Files ~ ".passwd">
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Virtualhost *:80>
            ServerName newlookandfell.mycustomer.com
            ServerAlias newlookandfell.mycustomer.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/my.website.com/html
            ErrorLog logs/mycustomer-error_log
            CustomLog logs/mycustomer-access_log common

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
            RewriteLogLevel 1
            ProxyPreserveHost On

    </VirtualHost>
```

Then i have a php file that, based on the session varialbe SERVER_NAME selects which L&F to include

```
    class ConfigLoader
    {
        /**
         * Determine URL used for accessing the page and load proper config file
         * @return
         */
        public static function loadConfiguration()
        {

            $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

            switch($server)
            {
                case 'newlookandfell.mycustomer.com':
                    require_once 'lookandfeel/mycustomer.php';
                    break;
                case 'lookandfell.anothercustomer.com':
                    require_once 'lookandfeel/anothercustomer.php';
                    break;
    ...... and so on
                default:
                    require_once 'lookandfeel/default.php';
                    break;
```

As i noticed that all the request to newlookandfell.mycustomer.com resolved to the default look and fell i checked in the Apache access_log (/etc/httpd/logs/access_log) and the request looks correct.

```
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [25/Nov/2019:07:42:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3379
"http://newlookandfell.mycustomer.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

But if i print the variable $server i get the public IP address. 
As a "patch" i modified the case to include the IP address but this is not a solution i like, what could i do if the next L&F has the same issue?

Do you have any idea why and how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Apache restarted after every change to the Virtual Host

Comment: Nobody has a clue to share? Some test i may run to shed some more light on this?